Efficient way to perform large spatial join between expansive point dataset and global country polygons?
I would like to partition the Overture Maps global building polygon dataset by country and I'm currently attempting to use Apache Sedona to accomplish this in a distributed manner, by spatially joining the building polygons (over 2B rows) to the country polygons (200 or so rows, but very complex geometry with many vertices) to assign a 'Country' column to the buildings. I tried to map the building polygons into centroids so I can do a more simple point-in-polygon join rather than polygon-in-polygon join. However, my job is taking considerably long to run, I last checked it at over 24 Hours and killed the job to conserve the resources.
My current implementation looks like this:
import org.apache.sedona.sql.utils.Adapter
import org.apache.sedona.core.spatialOperator.JoinQuery
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, expr, udf, element_at}
import org.apache.sedona.core.enums.{GridType, IndexType}

object OverturePartitioner {

  val NUM_PARTITIONS = 1000
  val OvertureReleasePath1 = "s3://overturemaps-us-west-2/release/2024-05-16-beta.0"

  val LatestOvertureReleasePath = "s3://overturemaps-us-west-2/release/2024-06-13-beta.0"
  val makeWKTPoint = udf((xmin: Float, ymin: Float, xmax: Float, ymax: Float) => {
    val x = (xmin + xmax) / 2
    val y = (ymin + ymax) / 2
    s"POINT ($x $y)"
  })

  def run(
    spark: SparkSession,
    outputPath: String,
    numPartitions: Int  
  ): Unit = {
    import spark.implicits._

    val countries = spark.read
      .parquet(s"$OvertureReleasePath1/theme=divisions")
      .where(
        col("type") === "division_area" and
          col("subtype") === "country"
      )
      .select(col("Country"), col("geometry"))

    val buildings = spark.read
      .parquet(s"$LatestOvertureReleasePath/theme=buildings/type=building")
      .select(
        col("id"),
        col("geometry"),
        col("bbox")
      )


    val countryWithGeom = countries.withColumn("geom", expr("ST_GeomFromWKB(geometry)"))
    val countrySpatial = Adapter.toSpatialRdd(countryWithGeom, "geom")
    val buildingsWithGeom = buildings
      .withColumn(
        "centroids",
        makeWKTPoint(
          $"bbox.xmin",
          $"bbox.ymin",
          $"bbox.xmax",
          $"bbox.ymax"
        )
      )
      .withColumn("geom", expr("ST_GeomFromWKT(centroids)"))
      .select(col("id"), col("geom"))

    val buildingsSpatial = Adapter.toSpatialRdd(buildingsWithGeom, "geom")

    buildingsSpatial.rawSpatialRDD.repartition(NUM_PARTITIONS)
    buildingsSpatial.analyze()
    buildingsSpatial.spatialPartitioning(GridType.KDBTREE, NUM_PARTITIONS)
    countrySpatial.spatialPartitioning(buildingsSpatial.getPartitioner)

    val buildOnSpatialPartitionedRDD = true
    buildingsSpatial.buildIndex(IndexType.RTREE, buildOnSpatialPartitionedRDD)

    val considerBoundaryIntersection = true
    val usingIndex = true
    val joined = JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQueryFlat(
      buildingsSpatial,
      countrySpatial,
      usingIndex,
      considerBoundaryIntersection
    )

    val buildingsJoined = joined.rdd
      .map {
        case (country, building) =>
          (
            building.getUserData.toString.split("\t")(0),
            country.getUserData.toString.split("\t")(0)
          )
      }
      .toDF("id", "country")

    buildings.join(buildingsJoined, "id").write.partitionBy("country").parquet(outputPath)

Are there any additional optimizations I can include which would increase the effciency of this query? I cant find any further documentation through Apache Sedona to offer any additional optimizations for this type of job, perhaps it cannot be optimized any further and this is the limit of Apache Sedona. Are there any other viable alternatives to do this type of spatial partitioning at this scale outside of Apache Sedona?

Try subdividing the countries so that the index is more specific

I see, so maybe index by a nested administrative hierarchy like 'state' within the country, so that sedona may be able to partition the data so that it is more closely together? I was under the impression that
buildingsSpatial.rawSpatialRDD.repartition(NUM_PARTITIONS)
buildingsSpatial.analyze()
buildingsSpatial.spatialPartitioning(GridType.KDBTREE, NUM_PARTITIONS)

builds a tree index on the building centroid table and
countrySpatial.spatialPartitioning(buildingsSpatial.getPartitioner)
ensures that the buildings are on the same partition as their enclosing country?

States might still result in quite complex polygons. The easiest is to create a rectangular grid and create a layer with the intersection of the countries and this grid. This way the vast majority of intersections of (centroids of) buildings with countries to be computed will be with simple rectangles, which will give a huge difference.

Are you attached to Sedona? If not, consider using Google BigQuery. This query took 36 seconds and run in free (Sandbox) tier:
select d.names.primary, count(*) cnt 
from `bigquery-public-data.overture_maps.building` b
join `bigquery-public-data.overture_maps.division_area` d
on st_intersects(b.geometry, d.geometry)
where d.subtype = 'country'
group by d.names.primary
order by cnt desc

I've printed counts, but similarly you can keep the full result set.
1   India                    433323993
2   United States of America 154632372
3   Brasil                   115620105
4   Indonesia                110963126
5   Rossiya                   71895191
...

